# Пробел через каждые N символов при выводе строки

Tags: c#, консоль, вывод, экран

Прошу подсказать, как сделать пробел в строке при выводе ее на экран.

Есть строчка

```
string str ="abcdefg1234567qwertyuzxcvbnm";
```

Хочу, чтобы при выводе было abcdefg 1234567 qwertyu zxcvbnm.
То есть, через каждые 7 ставило пробел.

```
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Через цикл пробывал, но как-то не идет.

Может это как-то через Split() сделать ?

Comment: Покажите, как Вы "пробывали".

Comment: Работай со строкой как массивом символов. Останется лишь разделить на нужное количество символов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Хм. Цикл + StringBuilder - вот и все дела:

```
void Main()
{
    string str ="abcdefg1234567qwertyuzxcvbnm";
    string result = SplitStr(str, 7);
    //result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public string SplitStr(string str, int maxSymbols)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var counter = 0;
    foreach (var element in str)
    {
        if (counter == maxSymbols)
        {
            sb.Append(" ");
            counter = 0;
        }

        sb.Append(element);
        counter++;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Вариант с регуляркой:

```
string str = "abcdefg1234567qwertyuzxcvbnm";
string res = Regex.Replace(str, ".{7}", "$0 ");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Linq-вариант:

```
string str = "abcdefg1234567qwertyuzxcvbnm";
var res = string.Concat(str.Select((c, i) => c + (i % 7 == 6 ? " " : "")));
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Но на самом деле вам нужно использовать вариант со `StringBuilder`, предложенный в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошие ответы уже были даны. 
Приведу лишь еще один Linq-вариант:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> input, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, input.Where(it=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(it)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Chunk(this string input, int size)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || size <= 0)
            return new Enumerable.Empty<string>();

        return Enumerable
            .Range(0, input.Length / size)
            .Select(i => input.Substring(i * size, size))
            .Concat(input.Length % size > 0 ? new[] {input.Substring(input.Length / size * size) } : new Enumerable.Empty<string>());
    }
}
```

применение:

```
"abcdefg1234567qwertyuzxcvbnm".Chunk(7).Join(" ");
```